# Filtering JSON data for analysis using Hive

Tags: hive

How can we filter the JSON data so that I can get only the selected fields into a file and later use this file for further analysis.

Comment: Please provide what you have done and also the same input/output.

Comment: I am trying to analyze twitter data and the key I got the tweets for "apache spark". I have got the files which contains the tweets from twitter. The JSON data has many fields like filter_level, retweeted, truncated, lang and many such fields. How do I filter it such a way that I get to store only a few fields like the text, name, userid etc in a file, so that I can use that file for further analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You must use Lateral View with json_tuple

json_tuple() UDTF is introduced in Hive 0.7. It takes a set of names (keys) and a JSON string, and returns a tuple of values using one function

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE twitterdata
(
json STRING 
)
LOCATION  'hdfs path';
```

If file on local filesystem

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'local path to file' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE twitterdata;
```

If file on hdfs

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs path to file' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE twitterdata
```

Create target table from which u can do further analysis

```
 CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE targettable
 (
    text string,
    name string,
    userid string
 )
LOCATION  'hdfs path';
```

Now load data using  **json_tuple**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE targettable
    select a.text
        ,a.name
        ,a.userid
    from twitterdata t.json
    LATERAL VIEW json_tuple (t.json,'text','name','userid')a
    as text,name.userid;
```

Done!!!